# Save matlab output to text file

Tags: matlab, permutation

I am running a script in Matlab to obtain a random permutations test of a matrix in order to obtain cross-validation accuracy values. My script is as follows:

```
%randperm 

labels = [zeros(40,1); ones(40,1)];

for i = 1:500
    p = labels(randperm(length(labels))); 
end


bestcv = 0; 
for log2c = -10:10, 
    for log2g = -10:10, 
        cmd = ['-s 0 -t 0 -v 20 -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g) ' -q     ']; 
        cv = svmtrain(labels, p, cmd); 
        if (cv > bestcv),
            bestcv = cv; bestc = 2^log2c; bestg = 2^log2g;
            fprintf('%g %g %g (best c = %g, g = %g, rate = %g)\n', log2c, log2g, cv, bestc, bestg, bestcv);
        end
    end
end
cmd = ['-s 0 -t 0 -c ', num2str(bestc), ' -g ', num2str(bestg)];
```

I am wondering how I can save the output (500 cross-validation accuracy values) into a text file, and if it is possible to write this into my code.

Thanks in advance,

Andrea C

Answer (score 0):

You can save the variable(s) containing your cross-validation results using `save` and load them later using `load`. For example, assuming you have the results in the variable called `accuracies`:

```
save('cross-validation-results.txt',accuracies);
```

and later

```
load('cross-validation-results.txt');
```

to reobtain the variable `accuracies`.

To implement this in your code, save the tuning parameters and the associated accuracy into arrays and then save said arrays.

Comment: I understand the save function, however in order to do this I would need to save my entire 'for' loop in the variable (accuracies). Is there a way to do this without disrupting the loop? (Sorry - I am fairly new to Matlab)

Comment: What do you mean by *disrupting the loop*? If you want to save *all* intermediate results (e.g. all the accuracies), you will need to store them somehow. There is no way around that I'm afraid.

Comment: ok. Thank you for your help. I am unable to add a variable assignment to the loop that produces the accuracies without getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `save` as Marc Claesen described it.

Nevertheless, if you just need a crude, fast way to somehow save your values, you could use matlabs `diary` command.

It saves all inputs and outputs to a textfile.

```
diary('cross-validation-output.txt')
```

To stop writing to the file you need to call

```
diary OFF
```